# Define a custom slot type that is no list

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am trying to code a youtube-subscriber-amount skill for Alexa.

If you ask "Alexa, ask subscribercounter for the subscribercount of {Channel}" I want to return {Channel}s subscribercount using youtube data api v3. My Problem is that I'm not sure how to create a slot in Alexa's interaction model, allowing all "strings" (Channelnames).

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031245/how-do-i-define-a-custom-slot-type-that-isnt-a-list) about two years ago but, it didn't really help me, since the solution was using LITERAL, which isn't available any longer. I've also seen [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47829211/9035603) answer, and I tried putting in only "wordOne" but I always get "undefined" if I'm logging the slotvalue in aws. Can anyone help me with creating a slot, allowing every input?

Comment: regarding the latter solution. can you provide the intent schema to your skill and the sample utterances.

Comment: `AMAZON.LITERAL` is still around but only available for English (US) skills. https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/custom-interaction-model-reference.html#literal